# How to handle integer overflow in LogParser?

Tags: integer-overflow, logparser

I'm selecting `Sum(time-taken)` from a big period of time logs and it is getting negative values. How do I handle it?

Comment: You could try doing a sum of `TO_REAL(time-taken)`.

Comment: @GabrieleGiuseppini It worked. If you want, put an answer here and I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try doing a sum of `TO_REAL(time-taken)`.